# Cannot create automated build in dockerhub from github

Tags: dockerhub

I am having trouble creating a new automated build in Dockerhub, using the Github link.

I cannot create an automated build from my Github account link that is already building against another repo. It is currently linking to the same account in Github that one of my Dockerhub builds is already using, but when I try to create a new automated build it does not display any linked accounts. I then go through the process of linking, which then tells me its already linked.

No idea whats up with this but its super annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by un-linking then re-linking my github account. It is now working fine.